# Inserir arquivo JSON no banco de dados via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo, foreach

Tenho um arquivo JSON que preciso fazer o insert das informações contidas nele no banco de dados.

Arquivo JSON:

```
{"retorno":{"produtos":[{"produto":{"codigo":"AAAAAA","estoqueAtual":20}},{"produto":{"codigo":"BBBBBB","estoqueAtual":10}}]}}
```

Como estou tentando fazer o insert:

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname','root','');

$jsondata = file_get_contents('bling.json');
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

$stmt = $db->prepare("insert into bling values(?,?)");


foreach ($data as $row) {

$stmt->bindParam(1, $row['produtos']['produto']['codigo']);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $row['produtos']['produto']['estoqueAtual']);
$stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

Porém, dessa forma, não consigo inserir nenhuma informação no banco de dados.

Se eu faço dessa mesma forma, acrescentando o `[0]` ele funciona:

```
foreach ($data as $row) {

$stmt->bindParam(1, $row['produtos'][0]['produto']['codigo']);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $row['produtos'][0]['produto']['estoqueAtual']);
$stmt->execute();
}
```

Mas só pega o primeiro valor (0) do arquivo JSON. Caso eu coloque `[1]` ele pega o segundo valor, e assim por diante.

Precisava de uma sugestão de como melhorar o código para que eu consiga capturar e inserir no banco de dados todos os valores que estão dentro do JSON.

Comment: Quando vc dar um var_dump em $data como fica? vc ja tentou adicionando o campo "chave" no foreach? foreach ($data as $key => $row)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chave mais externa do json `retorno` o foreach tenta iterar ela e não dá o resultado esperado, nesse caso você deve espeficicar onde varia ou seja indicar no foreach.

Mude:

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
```

Para:

```
foreach ($data['retorno']['produtos'] as $row) {
   $stmt->bindParam(1, $row['produto']['codigo']);
   $stmt->bindParam(2, $row['produto']['estoqueAtual']);

   $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Resolveu na hora! Valeu!